# Error When Moving Yii Boilerplate Project From Windows to Linux

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii, lampp

I have Moved `Yii` project from `Windows` to `Linux(Centos)` also changed folder and file permission to `read` and `write`, But when accessed, an error occured:

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
```

In the error logs:

```
[Sat Apr 27 14:54:50.753643 2013] [core:alert] [pid 2153] [client ::1:40135] /opt/lampp/htdocs/ehilal/backend/www/.htaccess: FilterProvider takes three arguments, filter-name provider-name match-expression
```

`.htaccess` part that declaring `FilterProvider` :

```
<IfModule filter_module>
  FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type /text/(html|css|javascript|plain|x(ml|-component))/
  FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type /application/(javascript|json|xml|x-javascript)/
  FilterChain     COMPRESS
  FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
```

How to fix it?
Thanks,

Comment: First check error_log file

Comment: Check your Apache and PHP error logs. Chances are your .htaccess requires a module that isn't loaded (`mod_rewrite` comes to mind).

Comment: @GBD, @DCoder: See edit, Should I add `.htaccess` file? but what the contents of it?

Comment: @GBD did you mean `mod_rewrite` ? It have been loaded but still showing the same way.

Comment: @DCoder It have been loaded but still showing the same way.

Comment: Are you running Apache 2.4? then check out this [github issue](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1012) with FilterProvider

Comment: It seems to work @jamie0726. You could put last code in the link as the answer and i'll make it as an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter provider directive has changed from httpd 2.2:

This [Github issue](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1012) suggests the following fix to include in the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_filter.c>                                                   
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                      application/javascript \
                                      application/json \
                                      application/rss+xml \
                                      application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                      application/x-font-ttf \
                                      application/xhtml+xml \
                                      application/xml \
                                      font/opentype \
                                      image/svg+xml \
                                      image/x-icon \
                                      text/css \
                                      text/html \
                                      text/plain \
                                      text/x-component \
                                      text/xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```